# Converting Jira File Binary to a Normal File

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

### Problem

I am using the Jira Rest API to fetch a file (could be a pdf, image, csv, or anything) here is the endpoint that I am using [Jira Get Attachment Content](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-attachments/#api-rest-api-3-attachment-content-id-get). I also receive a 200 with the following data:

```json
{
  status: 200, // NOTE I won't have the Location header since its a 200!
  headers: {
    // bunch of headers
  },
  output: "%PDF-1.3\r\n%����\r\n\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Catalog\r\n/Outlines 2 0 R\r\n/Pages 3 0 R\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Outlines\r\n/Count 0\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Pages\r\n/Count 2\r\n/Kids [ 4 0 R 6 0 R ] \r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n\r\n4 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Page\r\n/Parent 3 0 R\r\n/Resources <<\r\n/Font <<\r\n/F1 9 0 R \r\n>>\r\n/ProcSet 8 0 R\r\n>>\r\n/MediaBox [0 0 612.0000 792.0000]\r\n/Contents 5 0 R\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n\r\n5 0 obj\r\n<< /Length 1074 >>\r\nstream\r\n2 J\r\nBT\r\n0 0 0 rg\r\n/F1 0027 Tf\r\n57.3750 722.2800 Td\r\n( A Simple PDF File ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 688.6080 Td\r\n( This is a small demonstration .pdf file - ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 664.7040 Td\r\n( just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 652.7520 Td\r\n( text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 628.8480 Td\r\n( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 616.8960 Td\r\n( text. And more text. Boring, zzzzz. And more text. And more text. And ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 604.9440 Td\r\n( more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 592.9920 Td\r\n( And more text. And more text. ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 569.0880 Td\r\n( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 557.1360 Td\r\n( text. And more text. And more text. Even more. Continued on page 2 ...) Tj\r\nET\r\nendstream\r\nendobj\r\n\r\n6 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Page\r\n/Parent 3 0 R\r\n/Resources <<\r\n/Font <<\r\n/F1 9 0 R \r\n>>\r\n/ProcSet 8 0 R\r\n>>\r\n/MediaBox [0 0 612.0000 792.0000]\r\n/Contents 7 0 R\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n\r\n7 0 obj\r\n<< /Length 676 >>\r\nstream\r\n2 J\r\nBT\r\n0 0 0 rg\r\n/F1 0027 Tf\r\n57.3750 722.2800 Td\r\n( Simple PDF File 2 ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 688.6080 Td\r\n( ...continued from page 1. Yet more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 676.6560 Td\r\n( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 664.7040 Td\r\n( text. Oh, how boring typing this stuff. But not as boring as watching ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 652.7520 Td\r\n( paint dry. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj\r\nET\r\nBT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 640.8000 Td\r\n( Boring.  More, a little more text. The end, and just as well. ) Tj\r\nET\r\nendstream\r\nendobj\r\n\r\n8 0 obj\r\n[/PDF /Text]\r\nendobj\r\n\r\n9 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Type /Font\r\n/Subtype /Type1\r\n/Name /F1\r\n/BaseFont /Helvetica\r\n/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n\r\n10 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Creator (Rave \\(http://www.nevrona.com/rave\\))\r\n/Producer (Nevrona Designs)\r\n/CreationDate (D:20060301072826)\r\n>>\r\nendobj\r\n\r\nxref\r\n0 11\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000019 00000 n\r\n0000000093 00000 n\r\n0000000147 00000 n\r\n0000000222 00000 n\r\n0000000390 00000 n\r\n0000001522 00000 n\r\n0000001690 00000 n\r\n0000002423 00000 n\r\n0000002456 00000 n\r\n0000002574 00000 n\r\n\r\ntrailer\r\n<<\r\n/Size 11\r\n/Root 1 0 R\r\n/Info 10 0 R\r\n>>\r\n\r\nstartxref\r\n2714\r\n%%EOF\r\n",
}
```

And the above output which seems like some sort of encoded PDF, what I am not able to do is if I encode it back it puts out a corrupt pdf, it works with simple PDF but pdf with boxes and images are completely broken!

```js
// other stuff data is fetched here
// Convert the string to a Buffer
const pdfBuffer = Buffer.from(data.output, 'utf-8');

// Write the Buffer to a file
fs.writeFileSync(filename, pdfBuffer, {
    encoding: 'binary',
});
```

I have tried with different encodings and stuff but everytime it fails! Can someone please help or provide feedback so as to why this might be happening!

#### What exactly I am trying to do?

I am trying to upload a file over to a Jira comment and trying to fetch it using the Jira REST API! I am able to get the data however the received data does not convert into expected file!

Comment: Do the headers mention some charset or encoding? I would not be surprised if they utf-8 encoded your file, as JSON requires utf-8 strings.

Comment: @Botje these are some headers that seemed important!
`headers:{"content-type":"image/png","content-disposition":"attachment;filename=\"Screenshot(2aed8643-b5f3-4b0c-9e95-212849325ba7).png\";filename*=UTF-8''Screenshot%202024-01-04%20at%201.32.56%E2%80%AFPM%20%282aed8643-b5f3-4b0c-9e95-212849325ba7%29.png","accept-ranges":"bytes",},`

Comment: Post a complete request with header and response body. Including the request you made. Not just the on you **think** they are important.